# Help with Calculated Formula

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to create a calculated field column but its not being accepted. I'm trying to write a syntax for `if 'column 1' = 'value1'` and `'column 2' does not equal 'value2'` then `return 'employee name'`. I am the furthest from an expert but I have tried:

```
=IF([Column1]="value1"and[Column2]<>”value2”,"employee name")
=IF(AND([Column1]=”value1”,[Column2]<>”value2”,”employee name”)
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(AND([Column1]="value1",[Column2]<>"value2"),"employee name","")
```

May be you just miss to add third parameter to your IF clause. IF clause here must have 2 branches - one THEN and other ELSE.
Or may be if you use some special locale (switzerland or something german) then you must replace comma to semicolon as formula parts delimiter.

```
=IF(AND([Column1]="value1",[Column2]<>"value2");"employee name";"")
```

or

```
=IF(AND([Column1]="value1";[Column2]<>"value2");"employee name";"")
```

See this calculated formulas reference if needed.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)

Comment: Thank you so very much, I know it's easy to miss something so small but this worked

Comment: Please specify answer as best answer if it works. =)